# div element moving up and down while refreshing the page

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a wave effect in css, for that was trying to put a big rotating div with rounded corner at bottom of the page.

But for each refresh of the page, it is moving up or down with no reason, no matter what I was doing.
I don't know it is bad idea to put a div larger size than page itself. But I am not getting any reason why it is jumping around.

```html
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
clip: auto;
position: absolute;
overflow: hidden;
}

div {
  width: 500vh;
  height: 500vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;

border-top-left-radius: 40%;
  border-top-right-radius: 45%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 35%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 40%;
}

@keyframes example{
  from{ transform: rotate(0deg);}
  to{ transform: rotate(360deg);}

}
```

here is complete HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    html {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      clip: auto;
      position: absolute;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    div {
      width: 500vh;
      height: 500vh;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      background-color: red;
      animation-duration: 10s;
      animation-name: example;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      border-top-left-radius: 40%;
      border-top-right-radius: 45%;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 35%;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 40%;
    }
    
    @keyframes example {
      from {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
      }
      to {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div></div>

</body>

</html>
```

please help
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your body properties aren't defined, simply add it like so :

```
html,body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  clip: auto;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

---

To avoid problems like these, I would recommend always **using a div container** and not relying on html and body (which behavior is not always constant between browsers).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    html,body {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      clip: auto;
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    div#wavecontainer {
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        top: 0%;
        left: 0%;
        position:relative;
    }
    
    div#wave {
      width: 500vh;
      height: 500vh;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      background-color: red;
      animation-duration: 10s;
      animation-name: example;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      border-top-left-radius: 40%;
      border-top-right-radius: 45%;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 35%;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 40%;
    }
    
    @keyframes example {
      from {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
      }
      to {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="wavecontainer">
        <div id="wave"></div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```